# Vuejs lifecycle issues, data array is only populated after Webpack loader refreshed the element on the page? google maps markers not showing up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, webpack

I'm pretty new to vueJS, and I'm making an app where I can plot locations, and have them show up on a google maps element. My code is really hacky, but I'm trying to learn by making stuff. Thanks for any help.

**Context**

I currently have an array of geese objects:

```
[
    {
        "id": 74,
        "created_at": "Jan 14 08:24:46 PM",
        "latitude": "<a coord near me>",
        "longitude": "<a coord near me>"
    },
    {
        "id": 73,
        "created_at": "Jan 14 06:56:33 PM",
        "latitude": "<a coord near me>",
        "longitude": "<a coord near me>"
    }
]
```

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to convert this array of geese objects into another array of markers, containing position objects with just lat/long, which I can pass into google maps and show markers.

**Problems**

The map is showing up, and getting current location + centering is working fine.

For some reason, my markers array only gets populated when my webpack loader reloads the element on the page (for example, if I make a random console.log statement within my "getMarkers()" method. It isn't populating correctly when the page initially loads. I've tried looking through vue's lifecycle documentation, but just can't get it to work.

Additionally, when the markers do load correctly (checked with vue devtools chrome extension), they still don't appear as markers on the app (but when I manually enter in mock coors with vue devtools, they do?).

**My code**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <gmap-map :center="this.center" :zoom="15" style="width:100%;  height: 400px;">
      <gmap-marker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in markers"
        :position="m.position"
      ></gmap-marker>
    </gmap-map>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "GoogleMap",
  props: {
    geese: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      markers: [],
      center: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    geolocate() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.center = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
      });
    },
    getMarkers() {
      console.log("in getMarkers")
      for (var goose of this.geese) {
        console.log("got into for loop of geese")
        console.log("dsdfss")
        const marker = {
          lat: parseFloat(goose.latitude),
          lng: parseFloat(goose.longitude)
        };
        this.markers.push({ position: marker });
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.geolocate();
    this.getMarkers()
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: try changing `mounted` into `created`.

Comment: doesn't solve the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue!

my mounted code looks like this:

```
mounted() {
  document.onreadystatechange = () => {
     if (document.readyState == "complete") {
       console.log('Page completed')
       this.getMarkers()
     }
   }
}
```

i also put "this.geolocate()" into created